# Constructors similar to three.js ones

Tags: javascript, three.js, javascript-objects

I create a simple library for drawing graphs of math functions. I would like to make a constructors similar to three.js ones.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
```

For example, in my library to create a grid, you must write something like this:

```
var grid = new Charter.Grid();
```

I discovered that it can be done by `Object.assign()` method, but i don't know details of this solution. Therefore, I'd like to ask how to do this? I would be grateful for some examples of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler than you think.

```js
var MYLIB = {};

MYLIB.whatever = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

//

obj = new MYLIB.whatever(42);
console.log(obj);
```

Do note, however, that this pattern is outdated, it's better to use  modules (`require()` or `import`) in modern javascript.